# Given, $x=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta$, then find $x-x^{-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given, $x=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta$, then find $x-x^{-1}$?

---

My attempt:

It's a Euler formula as :
$$x=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta=e^{i\theta}$$

And, also

$$\cos \theta -i \sin \theta=e^{-i\theta}$$

I have tried it to solve as :
(there is two different solution possible!)

$\color{blue}{\text{First solution}}$

$x-x^{-1}=x-\cfrac{1}{x}=\cfrac{x^2-1}{x}=\cfrac{e^{2i\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}}$

But, there is confusion to get the correct value (ambiguity):

$\color{red}{\text{Second solution}}$

$x-x^{-1}=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta -\cos \theta +i \sin \theta=2i\sin\theta$

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Are they not the same thing?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, yes you are correct. Both are equivalent, that's my silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\frac{e^{2i\theta} - 1}{e^{i\theta}} = {e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}} = 2i\sin\theta
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} -\mathrm{e}^{-i\theta}}{2i} = \sin \theta
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} -\mathrm{e}^{-i\theta} = 2i\sin \theta
$$
and finally
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{i\theta}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}}= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2i\theta}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}}
$$